# Excel MATCH function is not working on an array but works once directed to the matched value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My problem specifically is knowing why this happened and how to fix it?

I am running a verification if a value exists on one of my sheets using ISNUMBER and MATCH functions. Upon getting the first test, some returned FALSE. So I checked on the source data manually if this really did not exist; but it happened to be there. So I checked and made a second test where I use the ISNUMBER and MATCH functions as well - but directed only to the exact cell of the matched value, then it returned TRUE!!

I want to ask why can't excel find a match on an array but can find it when directed to the exact cell?? And how can I fix it?

[image: Screenshot of my Problem]

Comment: Post few data from `Sheet2!B2:B417`.

Comment: You should be `FALSE` (or, equivalently, `0`) as `MATCH`'s third parameter.

Comment: Do you want to match partially? Means if the lookup value is exist in any part of cells you want result as true?

Comment: According to the definition here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a if you do not define the match type, the lookup array must be in ascending order.  See also the examples shown there.

Comment: It should work if you add the match type as proposed by Jos Woolley.

Comment: @JosWoolley this solved my problem. I added the third parameter and now it functions correctly. Thanks

Comment: Note the third parameter is *not* a boolean, unlike VLOOKUP. Its appropriate values are 1,0, or -1 depending on need.

Comment: I know this has been resolved but another easy way to check if a value exists is just using COUNTIF. In your casem something like `COUNTIF(Sheet2!B2:B147,A2)` should work

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns True, but `MATCH` will stop when it finds the first occurrence, whereas `COUNTIF` will keep computing until the last row referenced. With small ranges and few formulas this will not amount to much of a difference, though over larger ranges and a large number of formulas, that difference could become significant.